# Why is this global value treated as a local value?(python)

Tags: python, function, tkinter, scope

I am writing a tic-tac-toe program and I noticed that the "turn" value must have "global" before it. However, it is already considered a global value. Why is it treated as a local value? Out of all the other projects I have done, I have never encountered this problem. Further, all the other variables I have declared are already considered global here.

Here is the code:

```
players = ["O", "X"]
buttons = [[0,0,0],
           [0,0,0],
           [0,0,0]]
def newGame(): 
    turn = random.choice(players)

    def nextTurn(row, column):
        global turn
        if buttons[row][column]['text'] == "" and check_win == False:
            if turn == players[0]:
                buttons[row][column]['text'] = turn
                if check_win == False:
                    turn = players[1]
                    label.config(text=players[1] + " turn")
```

The problem seems to lie in the 'turn = players[1], but I do not know why.
Also, in a piece of sample code I experimented with, there was one instance that said the variable was not even defined, is it somehow connected to this problem? I have tried removing the global call, even in the sample code I learned from, where there were no nested functions, however, the same problem seems to occurs due to the line mentioned above. I have even tried making the variable an int or string, still the line mentioned above causes an error.

Comment: `turn` isn't a function; it's a `str` value.

Comment: whoops I meant variable

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `global` keyword to access the value of a global variable, but you **do** need `global` to assign a new definition to that global variable name.

Here's a simpler example to explain what's happening here.

```
x = 2

def test_1():
    print(x)

def test_2():
    x += 1
    print(x)

def test_3():
    global x
    x+=1 
    print(x)
```

You should find that `test_1()` and `test_3()` can be used without any issues, but `test_2()` throws an error.

Note: this does not necessarily prevent us from modifying global variables without the global keyword. For example, the following code runs without any error.

```
x=[10]

def test():
    x[0]+=1
    print(x)
```

---

Also, in particular your context, you should really be using `nonlocal` rather than `global` because you are using nested functions. Consider the following.

```
x=10

def test():
    x = 2

    def test_1():
        global x
        x+=1 
        print(x)
    
    def test_2():
        nonlocal x
        x+=1 
        print(x)
    
    test_1()
```

Try running this script and changing the `test_1()` call at the end to `test_2()`.

Comment: `turn` isn't global; it's non-local. Use `nonlocal` instead of `global`.

Comment: Your explanation is misleading. It is not relevant wether you want to read or modify some variable. The only thing that counts is that if there is some assignment to it somewhere in the function (even if it may never be actually executed), then the variable will be considered local unless declared otherwise (`global` or `nonlocal`). In such a situation, trying to access a variable to read it would lead to an `UnboundLocalError`

Comment: @ThierryLathuille I didn't realize that, thanks for correcting my misconception.

Comment: thanks! I just realized my mistake of calling turn a function, functions were on my mind and it slipped

Comment: @ThierryLathuille then wouldn't the buttons variable be considered local too? As there is an assignment to it.

Comment: @HouZeng No, you never change `buttons`, it still remains the same list, you only change the value of one of it's items. There is no `buttons = ...` anywhere in the function.

Comment: Thanks a lot :). By the way sorry if the question was a little misleading because I failed to check it thoroughly for mistakes.